# ¿Como puedo ocultar metodos en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing

Lo que sucede es que cree algunos componentes Gráficos que heredan de otros ya existentes de java.swing y pues lo hice "a mi manera", sin embargo, me gustaría que si alguien mas quiere usar esos componentes, utilice los nuevos métodos creados y no los que hereda del Componente original por lo que quiero ocultar todos aquellos métodos que pueden arruinar mis componentes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede / no se debe.

Si una clase hereda de, digamos, *JComponent*, entonces todas las instancias de esa clase son instancias de *JComponent*; es lo que se denomina la relación **es-un** (un *JButton* **es-un** *JComponent*).

O, dicho de otra forma, al extender una clase estás afirmando que la clase hija cumple el *contrato* que está definido en la clase padre. Ese contrato incluye los métodos definidos; tanto la signatura (nombre, parámetros) como su funcionamiento.

Es por eso que puedes hacer<sup>1</sup>:

```
JComponent miComponente = new MiJComponent();
```

la instancia creada **es-un** *JComponent* y se puede asignar, el compilador sabe que puede invocar *miComponente.paint()* (por ejemplo) porque ese método existe.

Lo cual nos lleva al principio de sustitución: debes poder sustituir una instancia de una clase por otra instancia de una subclase. Cuando quieras usar ese componente gráfico, lo querrás usar como cualquier otro componente. Así que tus métodos que heredan de *JComponent* deberán funcionar, porque serán los que Swing invocarán. Si haces

```
jPanel.add(new JButton("Hola"));
```

en algún momento Swing llamará a *paint()* de JButton y se ejecutará. Imagina que haces:

```
jPanel.add(new MiJButton("Hola"));
```

y que tu método *paint()* lanza, digamos, *NotSupportedException*... Pues cuando Swing lo invoque, el resultado será que no se pintará el componente.

En general la herencia implica que las clases hijas deben seguir fielmente el comportamiento de las clases padres. Si quieres más flexibilidad se puede usar composición en vez de herencia, pero en ese caso tu nueva clase no sería un *JComponent* y Swing no sabría cómo usarla.

---

<sup>1</sup>Algunos mensajes de programación te dejan hacer la asignación sin comprobar jerarquías y que se lance un fallo si has hecho una asignación incorrecta. Java prefiere comprobaciones estáticas.

Comment: Gracias me diste una idea con la clase MiJComponent, ya se como  hacerlo